# Converting strings that contain Uppercase letters to lower case letters

Tags: c, ascii

I need to be able to convert case in strings, so that `"Hello"` becomes `"hello"`.  Ultimately, I need to compare them.

How would I convert:

```
char *string = "HEllO";
```

to the string `"hello"`?

Comment: What exactly do you wan to compare? Do you only need to know if the input string contains upper case letters?

Comment: so do you eventually want to create a `compareToIgnoreCase` method? You can do that by converting the letters to lower case as you compare them and not saving the entire string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your string is not declared properly, it should be:

```
char *string = "Hello";
```

Now, to convert to lowercase, try this:

```
char *lowercase(const char *str)
{
    int length = strlen(str);
    char *dup = malloc(length + 1);
    strcpy(dup, str);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
         dup[i] = tolower(dup[i]);
    }

    return dup; // remember to free when done!
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with his definition of the string? `"HEllO"` is a valid string.

Comment: I guess Richard meant [revision 3](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1143ed2a-0333-4495-b243-3d81f560f3c8/view-source) of your question …

Answer (score 2):

Simply perform this inline.

```
   char string[] = "Hello";
   char * ptr;

   for (ptr = string; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr)
   {
       *ptr = tolower(*ptr);
   }
```

Comment: String literals are const. You will have a seg fault at runtime with your code. `char string[] = ...` would work.

Comment: (edit: kay got there before me) At least explain to him why this won't work

Comment: Corrected, yes the behavior would be "undefined".